# Groovy table sorting when the column is a sorted set of a class

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a a view that lists several contractor objects. The last column is from addresses which is a  sorted set in the contractor object. I am trying to sort those columns and I get an exception that the property addresses is not defined in class Contractors. Do I need to handle the sorted set differently in the controller?

```
<table width="100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <g:sortableColumn property="status" title="${message(code: 'contractor.status.label', default: 'Status')}" params="[statuses:statuses,name:name,nameOperator:nameOperator ?: 'CONTAINS']"/>
                    <g:sortableColumn property="contractorName" title="${message(code: 'contractor.contractorName.label', default: 'Name')}" params="[statuses:statuses,name:name,nameOperator:nameOperator ?: 'CONTAINS']"/>

                    <g:sortableColumn property="addresses.address" title='Address' params="[statuses:statuses,name:name,nameOperator:nameOperator ?: 'CONTAINS']"/>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${contractorList}" status="i" var="contractor">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">

                        <td>
                            <g:link action="show" id="${contractor.id}">show</g:link>
                            &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                            <g:link action="edit" id="${contractor.id}">edit</g:link>
                        </td>
                        <td>${contractor.status}</td>
                        <td>${contractor.contractorName}</td>
                        <td>${contractor?.addresses?.address}</td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The logic in the controller:

```
order(params.sort, params.order)
```

I am very new to groovy/grails any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is anything availabel out of the box for this but here is how I solved my similar issue. Basically I had to interecept sort param and do my own sorting.:

```
if (params.sort && params.sort == "state") {
  tasks =  Task.activeOnly.open.unassigned.list() //<--my query
  tasks = sortByState(tasks,params) //<--custom sort
 }
```

--- where sortByState is this:

```
private List sortByState(tasks, params){
        tasks.sort{Task.STATES.indexOf(it.state)} //<-- this is my custom sorter
        if (params.order == "DESC" ) {
            tasks = tasks.reverse()
        }
        def begin = params.int('offset') //<-- next two lines are for paging offsets
        def end = Math.min(begin+params.int('max'),tasks.size()-1)
        return tasks[begin..end]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks DmitryB! I'll give this a try and see how it goes.